# How do I programmatically bind a ContentControl's content to the DataContext?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, datacontext

Can someone help me translate this to CLR code:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SetBinding method:

```
ccDetails.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, new Binding())
```

Comment: I was affraid to use it, I thought that Binding inherits DataContext only when initialized in Xaml under an existing DataContexed control, I just leaned that it's dynamic, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Dim dc = ccDetails.GetValue(ContentControl.DataContextProperty)
ccDetails.SetValue(ContentControl.ContentProperty, dc)
```

Would love to hear about better ideas.

Comment: This is a one-time setvalue, not a binding declaration.  I think you would find that this doesn't update when an INotifyPropertyChanged event fires.

Comment: It worked for me even a property changed, I made a shallow unreliable test, I guess I will use itowlson's answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be something similar to this:

```
public void SetupManualBinding()
{
    var cc = new ContentControl();
    var binding = new Binding();
    cc.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, binding);
}
```

Comment: Nope, that will set the *value* of Content to a Binding object.  It won't *bind* the ContentProperty.